# Android webdriver sample Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

Tags: android, webdriver

System Info:

- win7x64
- android sdk 2.3.3

when I'm running android-sdk\extras\google\webdriver\TestAnAndroidWebApp

I got an error:  **Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.**

The test failed when it executes the line 'WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));'

```
public void testGoogleWorks() {
    driver.getWebView().getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.928.0 Safari/535.8");
    Log.d(getName(), "xxxxxxxxx");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com.hk");
    Log.d(getName(), driver.getCurrentUrl());
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    Log.d(getName(),searchBox.getTagName());
    //Log.d(getName(),searchBox.getText());
    //searchBox.sendKeys("Android Rocks!");
    //searchBox.submit();
    //String title = driver.getTitle();
    //assertTrue("Got title: " + title, title.contains("Google"));
    //assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Android")).size() > 1);
}
```

**the logcat:**

```
11-11 05:53:02.140: W/dalvikvm(521): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x4051a360 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405dcaf8 self=0x2bcfb8
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   | sysTid=530 nice=-1 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2903008
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   | schedstat=( 13138242077 3658568912 366 )
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:02.150: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:246)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1570)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:53)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:956)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-11 05:53:02.181: E/dalvikvm(521): VM aborting
```

**full log below:**

```
11-11 05:52:11.550: D/AndroidRuntime(473): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-11 05:52:11.550: D/AndroidRuntime(473): CheckJNI is ON
11-11 05:52:12.350: D/AndroidRuntime(473): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-11 05:52:12.381: D/AndroidRuntime(473): Shutting down VM
11-11 05:52:12.400: D/dalvikvm(473): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-11 05:52:12.400: D/dalvikvm(473): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-11 05:52:12.443: I/AndroidRuntime(473): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
11-11 05:52:13.060: D/AndroidRuntime(483): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-11 05:52:13.060: D/AndroidRuntime(483): CheckJNI is ON
11-11 05:52:13.930: D/AndroidRuntime(483): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-11 05:52:14.003: D/AndroidRuntime(483): Shutting down VM
11-11 05:52:14.010: D/dalvikvm(483): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-11 05:52:14.010: D/dalvikvm(483): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-11 05:52:14.021: I/AndroidRuntime(483): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
11-11 05:52:14.840: D/AndroidRuntime(493): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-11 05:52:14.840: D/AndroidRuntime(493): CheckJNI is ON
11-11 05:52:17.101: D/AndroidRuntime(493): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-11 05:52:17.241: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package simple.app uid=10036
11-11 05:52:17.311: I/ActivityManager(70): Start proc simple.app for added application simple.app: pid=501 uid=10036 gids={3003, 1015}
11-11 05:52:21.352: D/dalvikvm(501): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1448K, 61% free 2683K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 19ms+26ms
11-11 05:52:22.524: D/dalvikvm(501): GC_CONCURRENT freed 376K, 57% free 2903K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 15ms+21ms
11-11 05:52:23.501: D/dalvikvm(501): GC_CONCURRENT freed 748K, 59% free 2825K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 14ms+21ms
11-11 05:52:24.291: D/dalvikvm(501): GC_CONCURRENT freed 690K, 59% free 2777K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 32ms+19ms
11-11 05:52:25.142: D/dalvikvm(501): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 58% free 2869K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 14ms+14ms
11-11 05:52:26.011: I/TestRunner(501): started: testGoogleWorks(simple.app.test.SimpleGoogleTest)
11-11 05:52:26.150: I/TestRunner(501): finished: testGoogleWorks(simple.app.test.SimpleGoogleTest)
11-11 05:52:26.150: I/TestRunner(501): passed: testGoogleWorks(simple.app.test.SimpleGoogleTest)
11-11 05:52:26.201: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package simple.app uid=10036
11-11 05:52:26.201: I/Process(70): Sending signal. PID: 501 SIG: 9
11-11 05:52:26.280: D/AndroidRuntime(493): Shutting down VM
11-11 05:52:26.331: I/AndroidRuntime(493): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
11-11 05:52:26.350: D/dalvikvm(493): GC_CONCURRENT freed 111K, 71% free 298K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+16ms
11-11 05:52:26.350: D/jdwp(493): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
11-11 05:52:26.350: D/dalvikvm(493): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-11 05:52:27.571: D/AndroidRuntime(513): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-11 05:52:27.580: D/AndroidRuntime(513): CheckJNI is ON
11-11 05:52:29.420: D/AndroidRuntime(513): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-11 05:52:29.550: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package simple.app uid=10036
11-11 05:52:29.620: I/ActivityManager(70): Start proc simple.app for added application simple.app: pid=521 uid=10036 gids={3003, 1015}
11-11 05:52:32.103: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1449K, 61% free 2682K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 15ms+23ms
11-11 05:52:32.830: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 376K, 57% free 2901K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 14ms+16ms
11-11 05:52:33.760: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 748K, 59% free 2823K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 14ms+15ms
11-11 05:52:34.410: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 690K, 59% free 2775K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 14ms+15ms
11-11 05:52:35.070: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 58% free 2866K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 28ms+14ms
11-11 05:52:35.730: I/TestRunner(521): started: testGoogleWorks(simple.app.test.SimpleGoogleTest)
11-11 05:52:35.780: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=simple.app/.SimpleAppActivity } from pid 521
11-11 05:52:36.900: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 746K, 60% free 2703K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 15ms+95ms
11-11 05:52:38.220: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed simple.app/.SimpleAppActivity: +2s319ms
11-11 05:52:39.621: D/testGoogleWorks(521): xxxxxxxxx
11-11 05:52:41.241: W/InputManagerService(70): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4057d348 (uid=10013 pid=136)
11-11 05:52:43.522: D/dalvikvm(136): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 52% free 2878K/5895K, external 4652K/5293K, paused 186ms
11-11 05:52:49.310: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 121K, 54% free 3104K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 28ms+30ms
11-11 05:53:01.191: D/testGoogleWorks(521): http://www.google.com.hk/
11-11 05:53:01.390: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 254K, 49% free 3475K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 103ms
11-11 05:53:01.590: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 69K, 47% free 3834K/7111K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 69ms
11-11 05:53:01.782: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44K, 44% free 4225K/7495K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 68ms
11-11 05:53:02.140: W/dalvikvm(521): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x4051a360 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405dcaf8 self=0x2bcfb8
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   | sysTid=530 nice=-1 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2903008
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   | schedstat=( 13138242077 3658568912 366 )
11-11 05:53:02.140: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:02.150: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:246)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1570)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:53)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:956)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
11-11 05:53:02.181: I/dalvikvm(521):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-11 05:53:02.181: E/dalvikvm(521): VM aborting
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31): pid: 521, tid: 530  >>> simple.app <<<
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31):  r0 fffffec4  r1 deadd00d  r2 00000026  r3 00000000
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31):  r4 800a45c0  r5 4051a360  r6 80085acc  r7 002bd0f0
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31):  r8 44466b50  r9 43eb6e20  10 43eb6e08  fp 41edd8a0
11-11 05:53:02.350: I/DEBUG(31):  ip 800a4720  sp 44466678  lr afd19375  pc 80045a4a  cpsr 20000030
11-11 05:53:02.771: I/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00045a4a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.771: I/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 00037748  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.780: I/DEBUG(31):          #02  pc 00039a10  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.790: I/DEBUG(31):          #03  pc 0003a4ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.790: I/DEBUG(31):          #04  pc 002989d6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.803: I/DEBUG(31):          #05  pc 002120a4  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.810: I/DEBUG(31):          #06  pc 00113216  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.821: I/DEBUG(31):          #07  pc 00212b70  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.830: I/DEBUG(31):          #08  pc 002c716e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.830: I/DEBUG(31):          #09  pc 002ca646  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.850: I/DEBUG(31):          #10  pc 002d0bfa  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.860: I/DEBUG(31):          #11  pc 0010c7da  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.871: I/DEBUG(31):          #12  pc 0010c860  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.880: I/DEBUG(31):          #13  pc 00110e6a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.880: I/DEBUG(31):          #14  pc 00110fca  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.901: I/DEBUG(31):          #15  pc 0011c496  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
11-11 05:53:02.901: I/DEBUG(31):          #16  pc 00017d74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.911: I/DEBUG(31):          #17  pc 00048f54  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.911: I/DEBUG(31):          #18  pc 00041b16  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.930: I/DEBUG(31):          #19  pc 0001cfd4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.930: I/DEBUG(31):          #20  pc 000220dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.930: I/DEBUG(31):          #21  pc 00020fd0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.951: I/DEBUG(31):          #22  pc 0005f430  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.951: I/DEBUG(31):          #23  pc 0005f656  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.960: I/DEBUG(31):          #24  pc 00053b4e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:02.971: I/DEBUG(31):          #25  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:02.971: I/DEBUG(31):          #26  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:02.971: I/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
11-11 05:53:02.971: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a28 447a4479 ed0cf7d1 20004c09 ee34f7d1 
11-11 05:53:02.971: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a38 447c4808 6bdb5823 d0002b00 49064798 
11-11 05:53:02.982: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a48 700a2226 eea0f7d1 000436b7 00045275 
11-11 05:53:02.982: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a58 0005eb82 fffffec4 deadd00d b510b40e 
11-11 05:53:02.990: I/DEBUG(31): 80045a68 4c0a4b09 447bb083 aa05591b 6b5bca02 
11-11 05:53:02.990: I/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
11-11 05:53:03.001: I/DEBUG(31): afd19354 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
11-11 05:53:03.001: I/DEBUG(31): afd19364 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
11-11 05:53:03.001: I/DEBUG(31): afd19374 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
11-11 05:53:03.010: I/DEBUG(31): afd19384 bdf01c30 000281a8 ffffff88 1c0fb5f0 
11-11 05:53:03.020: I/DEBUG(31): afd19394 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
11-11 05:53:03.020: I/DEBUG(31): stack:
11-11 05:53:03.020: I/DEBUG(31):     44466638  00000015  
11-11 05:53:03.020: I/DEBUG(31):     4446663c  afd18407  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:03.020: I/DEBUG(31):     44466640  afd4270c  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:03.020: I/DEBUG(31):     44466644  afd426b8  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:03.030: I/DEBUG(31):     44466648  00000000  
11-11 05:53:03.030: I/DEBUG(31):     4446664c  afd19375  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:03.030: I/DEBUG(31):     44466650  002bcfb8  [heap]
11-11 05:53:03.030: I/DEBUG(31):     44466654  afd183d9  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:03.040: I/DEBUG(31):     44466658  002bd0f0  [heap]
11-11 05:53:03.040: I/DEBUG(31):     4446665c  0005eb82  [heap]
11-11 05:53:03.040: I/DEBUG(31):     44466660  4051a360  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
11-11 05:53:03.040: I/DEBUG(31):     44466664  80085acc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:03.050: I/DEBUG(31):     44466668  002bd0f0  [heap]
11-11 05:53:03.060: I/DEBUG(31):     4446666c  afd18437  /system/lib/libc.so
11-11 05:53:03.060: I/DEBUG(31):     44466670  df002777  
11-11 05:53:03.060: I/DEBUG(31):     44466674  e3a070ad  
11-11 05:53:03.060: I/DEBUG(31): #00 44466678  00000001  
11-11 05:53:03.073: I/DEBUG(31):     4446667c  8003774d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:03.081: I/DEBUG(31): #01 44466680  00000001  
11-11 05:53:03.081: I/DEBUG(31):     44466684  80039a15  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-11 05:53:08.532: I/BootReceiver(70): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
11-11 05:53:08.612: D/Zygote(33): Process 521 terminated by signal (11)
11-11 05:53:08.630: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '40795038 simple.app/simple.app.SimpleAppActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-11 05:53:08.630: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '40795038 simple.app/simple.app.SimpleAppActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-11 05:53:08.641: I/ActivityManager(70): Process simple.app (pid 521) has died.
11-11 05:53:08.651: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{40795038 simple.app/simple.app.SimpleAppActivity paused=false}
11-11 05:53:08.902: D/dalvikvm(70): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 806K, 48% free 4535K/8647K, external 3125K/3903K, paused 91ms
11-11 05:53:08.931: W/ActivityManager(70): Crash of app simple.app running instrumentation ComponentInfo{simple.app.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
11-11 05:53:08.941: D/AndroidRuntime(513): Shutting down VM
11-11 05:53:08.941: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package simple.app uid=10036
11-11 05:53:09.001: I/AndroidRuntime(513): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
11-11 05:53:09.041: D/dalvikvm(513): GC_CONCURRENT freed 108K, 71% free 299K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+2ms
11-11 05:53:09.041: D/jdwp(513): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
11-11 05:53:09.041: D/dalvikvm(513): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-11 05:53:09.251: W/InputManagerService(70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 521 uid 10036
```

Comment: seems to be sdk problem, run well in 2.2, but fails in 2.3.1/2.3.3

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Supported_Platforms
Note that there is an emulator bug on Gingerbread that might cause WebDriver to crash - altough they could specify what kind of bug it is

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error here, I fixed with this procedure:

- Ensure your target package is the correct one.
- Ensure you call your driver on the UI thread, something like this:

  ```
  this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          //load your driver here
      }
  });
  ```
- Ensure the activity or components you are testing are visible.
- If you are testing a big chunk of testCases, ensure you close each activity properly in the end of each execution, with **`getActivity.finish()`** and calling **`this.finishOpenedActivities()`** inside your tearDown() method

Hope this can help you..good luck